# ZMQ on Xampp (Windows)

Tags: php, zeromq

I've got a problem with the installation of the ZMQ Extension for PHP 5.5 on Windows.
I've successfully downloaded the file php_zmq.dll and libzmq.dll for Pecl. But if I'm trying to register the extension (I moved the files php_zmq.dll and libzmq.dll to the extension folder of PHP (C:\xampp\php\ext) and restarting the server, there always comes the message that libzmq.dll is required. But both files are in the same directory.
I've entered this in the php.ini:
extension=php_zmq.dll

I hope someone can help me. If you need some information, you can tell it to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The solution recording to the [wiki](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php#toc4) should be the following

> Copy libzmq.dll into your php directory (e.g.
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8)
>
> Copy the appropriate version of php_zmq.dll to your php extension
>   directory (e.g. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext)

The *libzmq.dll* goes not into the *~/php/ext/* folder. To install ZMQ with xampp you have to put the *libzmq.dll* into the xampp folder (~/xampp/)!

If it is not working, check if you downloaded the right package from http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq

Answer (score 3):

DO NOT COPY libzmq.dll to the ext folder, rather the php folder. Worked for me!